# catalog search meta tags

Tags: search

i have a problem with a client of mine using magento shop.
he have on google a catalog search result url, the system isnt using canonical in the settings, and i dont want to apply it as some of the url having high rank on google...

but their description is the default one... is there away to make a dynamic descriptions to those search result, for example, to have a static sentence and a dynamic word add.

like: "XXX have the best [dynamic word] in the world, come and buy it now", the [dynamic word] will come from the title tag...

what file should i edit to do it and where can i find it? :)

thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "their description is the default one"? give an example.

Comment: it gives me the name of the sites in all those seatch pages....

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not that clear but I'll give it a try.
You can observe the event `controller_action_layout_render_before_catalogsearch_result_index` and add the mata description that you want.

Your observer can look similar to this:

```
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Observer {
   public function setMetaDescription($observer) {
       $head = Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('head');
       if ($head) {
          $description = "Build your meta description here";
          $head->setDescription($description);
       }
   }
}
```